# MySQL/doctrine query to retrieve all elements greater than date

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, doctrine

I have a Symfony project with 2 entities like `Session 1 <-> n Timeslots`, (and many more other entities).

My problem is i can't find a query that would retrieve the list of Sessions where ALL the timeslots are greater than a given date. Is it possible to do it in one query?

I've tried with MIN (simplified version, without the extra JOIN with other entities):

```
SELECT s.id 
FROM session s
JOIN timeslot t ON t.sessionId = s.id
HAVING MIN(t.timelotDate) > '2019-05-05';
```

But i don't retrieve any element with this query.

I've made a sqlfiddle for it:
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b485b/5

Comment: I don't see a group by (and thanks to MySQL's stupidity the query works).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT session.id
FROM session
JOIN timeslot ON timeslot.sessionId = session.id
GROUP BY session.id
HAVING MIN(timeslot.timeslotDate) > '2019-05-05'
```

An alternate would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM session
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM timeslot
    WHERE timeslot.sessionId = session.id
    AND timeslot.timeslotDate <= '2019-05-05'
)
```

Comment: You are right about GROUP BY with HAVING clause : i retrieve results but for some reason i retrieve all the sessions id, not only those HAVING MIN(t.timelotDate) > '2019-05-05'... I'll try to make a sqlfiddle or such

Comment: @Overdose if you have a where clause that filters all past dates/future then `HAVING` idea will not work, `NOT EXISTS` could be plugged into your existing where clause though.

Comment: In my "real" query i have more joins with some many to many relationship (one of which is mandatory since there is also a filter on it). This is, i think, the core of the difference between your answer i have accepted and my more complex query. But the part concerning the question asked is ok for me. I just need to think of a way to override the problem.

Answer (score 0):

use `max()` and `group by`

```
SELECT s.id 
FROM session s
JOIN timeslot t ON t.sessionId = s.id group by s.id
having max(t.timelotDate) > '2019-05-05'
```

Comment: This would retrieve more results than expected : a session can have many timeslots, so with your query i would get any session with AT LEAST one timeslot > XX. I want to retrieve session with EACH/ ALL Timeslot > XX

Comment: what is  your expected answer